# Highest Win Over Reigning Champion In FIFA World Cup

Tags: football, trivia, history, world-cup

After having seen the Dutch team win their first group B match in the FIFA World Cup 2014, against the reigning world champion (Spain),
[image]

I was wondering what the highest win was ever against a reigning champion?

Comment: Is it for the first match or any match?

Comment: @hims056 would say any match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I searched for all games involving defending champions [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_World_Cup#Results). Spain's loss against the Netherlands is the biggest loss for any reigning world champion in terms of *goal difference* (1-5). The second biggest loss is by West Germany, who lost to France 3-6 in the third-place playoff of the [1958 World Cup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1958_FIFA_World_Cup#Knockout_stage). This is also the biggest loss in terms of *goals conceded*.